# woo commerce multiple booking solution

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to set up multiple bookings on Woo commerce, I have the Woo Commerce Bookings plugin from Woo themes and I cant find a way to do multiple bookings.

Is there any plugin or other method which would allow me to have multiple bookings.

For example the customer will sell 4 bookings at a discount, that can be booked at any available free time , such as 10 on Monday, 12.00 on Sunday, 11.00 the Following Tuesday and 15.00 the following Friday.